# Maui Android Can't Load From Bundle

Tags: android, load, bundle, maui

I have a Maui Android app that has been working, and all of a sudden has decided to crash out during start up.

Looking at the output window log it appears to be unable to extract dlls form the bundle.

I have include log from the output window, maybe this will help somebody identify the problem.

I've had to trim the logs a bit as it was too long to post.

```
Forwarding debugger port 8850
Detecting existing process
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.idsapp.DroidMR/crc640577e99985f53b54.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.idsapp.DroidMR/crc640577e99985f53b54.MainActivity }
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/DroidM.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Java.Interop.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Collections.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:124 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Threading.Thread.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0xb400007b28a56020 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0xb400007b28ae60b0 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0xb400007b78a47010 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0xb400007b28ad60a0 [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:419 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Text.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Private.Uri.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Loader.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:414 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Memory.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/CommunityToolkit.Maui.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Net.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.JSInterop.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Private.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/WeakEvent.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/MauiViewModel.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/XamlViewModel.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/CommandViewModel.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/ViewModel.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Utils.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.CSharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Console.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
Thread started: .NET Timers #2
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/AzureRemoteService.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Net.ServicePoint.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Net.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/ProtocolData.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Net.Requests.dll [External]
[.idsapp.DroidM] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[USNET] USNET: appName: com.idsapp.DroidMR
[ProcessState] Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll [External]
[CompatibilityChangeReporter] Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 11025; state: ENABLED
[.idsapp.DroidM] Entry not found
[.idsapp.DroidM] Entry not found
[.idsapp.DroidM] Entry not found
[.idsapp.DroidM] JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exist.
[.idsapp.DroidM] JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exist.
[.idsapp.DroidM] JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exist.
[GraphicsEnvironment] ANGLE Developer option for 'com.idsapp.DroidMR' set to: 'default'
[GraphicsEnvironment] App is not on the allowlist for updatable production driver.
[LoadedApk] LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext.mOpPackageName=com.idsapp.DroidMR appContext.mBasePackageName=com.idsapp.DroidMR
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[debug-app-helper] Checking if libmonodroid was unpacked to /data/app/~~Tip2sZxXFDx29fjKIeRxNg==/com.idsapp.DroidMR-VZi2CmR_gk2ZtYi1SlN9ZA==/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so
[debug-app-helper] /data/app/~~Tip2sZxXFDx29fjKIeRxNg==/com.idsapp.DroidMR-VZi2CmR_gk2ZtYi1SlN9ZA==/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so not found, assuming application/android:extractNativeLibs == false
[debug-app-helper] Setting up for DSO lookup directly in the APK
[debug-app-helper] Added APK DSO lookup location: /data/app/~~Tip2sZxXFDx29fjKIeRxNg==/com.idsapp.DroidMR-VZi2CmR_gk2ZtYi1SlN9ZA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
[debug-app-helper] Using runtime path: /data/app/~~Tip2sZxXFDx29fjKIeRxNg==/com.idsapp.DroidMR-VZi2CmR_gk2ZtYi1SlN9ZA==/lib/arm64
[debug-app-helper] checking directory: `/data/user/0/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/lib`
[debug-app-helper] directory does not exist: `/data/user/0/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/lib`
[.idsapp.DroidM] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[DOTNET] JNI_OnLoad: JNI_OnLoad in pal_jni.c
[monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__`
[.idsapp.DroidM] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8850,server=y,embedding=1
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly DroidM.dll
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Mono.Android.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Java.Interop.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.Thread.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
[.idsapp.DroidM] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly netstandard.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Linq.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Json.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ObjectModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Uri.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Loader.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Memory.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly CommunityToolkit.Maui.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Primitives.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.JSInterop.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Xml.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en-CA/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en-CA/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
[.idsapp.DroidM] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 250(28KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 2024KB/4072KB, paused 46us,19us total 5.411ms
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly WeakEvent.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly MauiViewModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly XamlViewModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly CommandViewModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly ViewModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Utils.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Linq.Expressions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.CSharp.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Console.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly AzureRemoteService.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Http.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.ServicePoint.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Security.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly ProtocolData.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Requests.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Data.Common.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Data.Common.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: .NET ThreadPool Gate #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll [External]
[OpenGLRenderer] RenderThread::requireGlContext()
[AdrenoGLES-0] QUALCOMM build                   : 3dad7f8ed7, I593c16c433
[AdrenoGLES-0] Build Date                       : 10/01/21
[AdrenoGLES-0] OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.02
[AdrenoGLES-0] Local Branch                     : 
[AdrenoGLES-0] Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.9.1.R1.11.00.00.604.073
[AdrenoGLES-0] Remote Branch                    : NONE
[AdrenoGLES-0] Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
[AdrenoGLES-0] Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
[AdrenoGLES-0] Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
[AdrenoGLES-0] PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll
[OpenGLRenderer] RenderThread::setGrContext()
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Cameras.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Cameras.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll [External]
Thread started:  #6
Thread started:  #7
Thread started:  #8
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en-CA/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en-CA/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll     [AndroidRuntime]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.IO.Compression.dll
**Java.Lang.NullPointerException:** 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel.setIsStateSaved(boolean)' on a null object reference'

Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.idsapp.DroidMR/files/.__override__/System.IO.Compression.dll [External]
```

Answer (score 8):

It appears that "open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly" is normal.
I just created another working test project and when it loads it gives the errors.

Comment: I guess you are correct. If you look at the build log you will see all the same dlls included in an android build, SQLite-net.dll -> SQLite-net.dll.so, and the debug shows  [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLite-net.dll. But the app is working ok.

Comment: I have same error. i try to go back to .net 7.0 ( i geuss you using .net 8.0 )

Comment: happened to me on .net 8, After digging, I noticed an async call (at app startup) to a method that used third-party packages that were not initialized properly yet.